# PyQt setSnapPositionsX(self, Iterable[float]): first argument of unbound method must have type 'QScroller'

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

What I try to accomplish is a scrollarea full of labels and you can swipe through them using QScroller. The error I got is **TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:
setSnapPositionsX(self, Iterable[float]): first argument of unbound method must have type 'QScroller'** .

```
class mainWindow(QMainWindow):
def __init__(self, parent=None):
    super().__init__(parent)
    uic.loadUi("form.ui", self)

    self.scroll_area = QScrollArea(self)
    self.scroll_area.setStyleSheet(f"font-size : 90px; font-weight : bold")
    self.scroll_area.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
    self.scroll_area.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)


    self.layoutt = QHBoxLayout(self)
    self.layoutt.addWidget(self.scroll_area)

    self.scroll_widget = QWidget(self)
    self.scroll_layout = QHBoxLayout(self.scroll_widget)
    self.scroll_area.setGeometry(QRect(100,300,900,160))

    for i in range(1,50):
        self.scroll_layout.addWidget(QLabel("0.{}   ".format(i)))
    
    self.scroll_area.setWidget(self.scroll_widget)

    QScroller.grabGesture(
        self.scroll_area.viewport(), QScroller.LeftMouseButtonGesture
    )
    QScroller.setSnapPositionsX(self.scroll_area.scroll(self.scroll_area), 0.0, 10.0)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
win = mainWindow()
win.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Now I know that the first argument in `QScroller.setSnapPositionsX(self.scroll_area.scroll(self.scroll_area), 0.0, 10.0)` is wrong, thus, this specific function accepts a **QScroller** type of parameter as the first argument. The problem is I cannot instantiate QScroller in a way `scroll = QScroller()` it gives the error **TypeError: PyQt5.QtWidgets.QScroller cannot be instantiated or sub-classed**. What exactly I should write to the first parameter of the setSnapPositionX function?

Comment: As shown in the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qscroller.html#details), you must use the static `scroller(target)` function: `scroller = QScroller.scroller(self.scroll_area)`.

Comment: Yes, because it was in c++, I guess I could not comprehend at first glance. Thanks a lot, this works.